# XBee Coordinator API not receiving data from Router AT pin 20

Tags: arduino, xbee, zigbee, python

A Xbee Series 2 in Router AT configuration with a potentiometer wiper output connected to XBee's pin 20 `AD0` is supposed to send the analog data every 100 ms. It was set with `ATD02` and `ATIR64`.

A Xbee Series 2 in Coordinator API config is connected to the computer.

Using XCTU terminal, we can see that the Coordinator is constantly receiving `Explicit RX Indicator` frames from the Router. However there are no frames containing the analog data read by `AD0` on the Router XBee.

[image]

[image]

Using Python with the `XBee` module, we also notice the same thing, just `rx_explicit` frames being received and nothing containing the analog data samples!

```
{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x02(', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}

{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x02I', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}

{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\xeb', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}

{'profile': '\xc1\x05', 'source_addr': '6T', 'dest_endpoint': '\xe8', 'rf_data': '\x01\x00\x00\x01\x01\xce', 'source_endpoint': '\xe8', 'options': '\x01', 'source_addr_long': '\x00\x13\xa2\x00@\xb1\x92\x13', 'cluster': '\x00\x92', 'id': 'rx_explicit'}
```

What do you think may have happened? I checked the value at `AD0` by reading it with an Arduino and indeed there is a value to be read.

Comment: Maybe you should provide a link that shows how connecting a pot to an ADC input will initiate data transmissions and not just sit there waiting for someone/something to instruct it to do just that.

Comment: @Andyaka I think if I set XBee to do at a fixed interval the reading from the ADC input pin and the transmitting of the read value, it should continuously transmit the data. The AT command used to do this was `ATD0 2` to enable the ADC read and `ATIR 64` to transmit every 100 ms.

Answer (score 1):

Did you configure the AD0 pin as analog properly?

- If you configured it properly, then it will send the IO sample frame.
- If you did not connect anything to AD0 then it will send garbage value in the IO sample frame.

A router must have to be configured in API mode to use its analog pin.

See [IO sampling using XBee](http://millionbit.blogspot.com/2014/04/io-sampling-using-xbee-apiadc-operation.html) for more information.